# Why the value here didn`t change by the function?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem here learning with javascript, as the book said 'this' is binding to where the function was called, why here val didn`t change?

```js
this.val = 'test'
function foo(p1,p2){
    console.log('val',this.val) // undefined, why is not 'test'
    this.val = p1+p2
    console.log('this.val',this.val) //ab
}

foo('a','b') 

console.log('test2',this.val) //test, why not 'ab'?
```

Comment: I've got: val test  / this.val ab / test2 ab with chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question #1 & #2,

When calling a function `this` is referring to the `global` object. **The `global` object depends on how you run your code?**, if you are executing in a browser, it is the `window` object. In node.js it is an object called `global`.

This in function calls points to the **global** object. It is not so simple though. **This behavior only applies when not in strict mode. When in strict mode, this in functions is `undefined`.** that's why  you are getting `undefined`, not 'test'

**with strict mode on,**

```js
"use strict"

this.val = 'test'
function foo(p1,p2){
    console.log('val',this.val) // undefined, why is not 'test'
    this.val = p1+p2
    console.log('this.val',this.val) //ab
}

foo('a','b') 

console.log('test2',this.val) //test, why not 'ab'?
```

**without strict mode on,**

```js
this.val = 'test'
function foo(p1,p2){
    console.log('val',this.val) // undefined, why is not 'test'
    this.val = p1+p2
    console.log('this.val',this.val) //ab
}

foo('a','b') 

console.log('test2',this.val) //test, why not 'ab'?
```

Comment: oooh, its really running in node.js, thanks a lot !

Comment: @Monophonic glad it helps you somehow, Happy Coding!